# Unintentionally closing </script> tags in a PHP function which generates JavaScript (itself called via JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php

*Apologies for the lengthy explanation, I'm aware it's a bit of an odd problem to have which is why I felt best to include full context to describe why I am doing things the way I am, and why I (perhaps incorrectly) feel this way is necessary.*

**Context**

As part of a web application, I need to allow users to add comments to documents. When a user clicks a link, they are redirected (through a mandatory corporate authentication page to confirm their identity) to a pop-up where they can enter the comment and click a 'Submit' button to add their comment.

When the user clicks Submit, I would like to `INSERT` the query into my MySQL database, then close the pop-up window and refresh the parent window (so the document displays with the newly added comment).

There is no issue with any of these elements. I can write a JavaScript function to respond to the `onclick` of the Submit button; I can query the database successfully; and I can refresh the parent window before closing the pop-up. *Individually* each of these elements works perfectly. My problem is combining them.

When I try to echo JavaScript out from the PHP function, it causes issues.

**Steps**

- **Step 1** The `onclick` of the Submit button calls a JavaScript function.
- **Step 2** This JavaScript function calls a PHP function to query the database.
- **Step 3** JavaScript must be generated within this PHP function to refresh the parent window and close the pop-up.

---

**Step 1**

The onclick of the Submit button calls the addCommentJS(); JavaScript function.

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='Add Comment' onclick='addCommentJS(); return false;'>";
```

---

**Step 2**

The addCommentJS() JavaScript function calls the PHP function addCommentPHP().

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "function addCommentJS()";
echo "{";
    echo 'document.write("', addCommentPHP() ,'");';
echo "}";
echo "</script>";
```

---

**Step 3**

Within the PHP function addCommentPHP(), after querying the database, JavaScript code should be generated to refresh the parent window and close the pop-up. **This is where problems occur.**

```
// Attempt 1

function addCommentPHP() 
{
    // Query the database etc. 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"; 
        echo "opener.location.reload();"; 
        echo "window.close();"; 
    echo "</script>"; 
}
```

Upon testing the first attempt, I see a `");}` output to the screen that I do not expect. When I View Source using F12, I see that it has generated -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addCommentJS()
    {
       document.write("
            <script type='text/javascript'> 
                opener.location.reload();
                window.close();
</script>");}
```

Okay, so, pretty obvious cause of the error. It's hitting the closing `</script>` tagging and closing the first `<script>` tag which was opened in AddCommentJS().

---

I decide to experiment by stripping out the tags to see what it generates this time.

```
// Attempt 2 

function addCommentPHP() 
{
    echo "opener.location.reload();";
    echo "window.close();";
}
```

This outputs `opener.location.reload()window.close()` directly into the window, and inspecting the code shows -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addComment()
    {
        document.write("
            opener.location.reload();
            window.close();
        ");
    }
</script>
```

---

Finally, I tried to close the first `<script>` tag, open another set and contain my code within these, then open another `<script>` tag. (Obviously this was expected to fail and largely an experiment to see what code would be generated.)

```
    // Attempt 3

function addComment() 
{
    echo "</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "opener.location.reload();";
        echo "window.close();";
    echo "</script>";
    echo "<script>";
}
```

This will refresh the parent window and close the pop-up window immediately (as expected). The code generated by this is -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addCommentJS()
    {
        document.write("
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close(); 
</script>

<script>
    ");}
</script>
```

---

Is there a way to prevent this issue from occurring?

---

**Edit:**

Previously I had everything (all the JavaScript) within `addCommentJS()`.

```
function addCommentJS() 
{
    document.write("', addComment() ,'");';
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
}
```

However, I was concerned that this would run asynchronously and cause the window to close before the query was run.

Comment: *Step 2* should use ajax to query the server, which will trigger the PHP code. Is it how you are doing it?

Comment: *Step 3*: why not have the server send a result code to the ajax caller, and upon that result code, have the js function execute the redirect?

Comment: Your way of doing things seems convoluted a bit.

Comment: Your step 2 is writing a javascript block inside a javascript block. That is not going to work. You should simplify this, write your javascript functions once and call them when needed. And `document.write()` is almost never a solution.

Comment: I have updated the question with a previous attempt I tried and reasons why I did not go with it.

Comment: @jeroen How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is what is commonly referred to as AJAX. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) has an article on it, as well there seems to be [Compilation of tutorials here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a JavaScript string literal for the `document.write()` call here:

```
echo 'document.write("', addCommentPHP() ,'");';
```

The problem is that it is not escaped correctly, i.e. angle brackets < and > still have their HTML meaning (and so `</script>` closes the script block). Try escaping with `json_encode()`, which automatically creates a valid JavaScript literal from a native PHP value (in this case a string which contains another script block):

```
echo 'document.write('.json_encode(addCommentPHP()).');';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the inner script tag like:

```
function addCommentPHP() 
{
    // Query the database etc. 
    echo '\x3Cscript type=\'text/javascript\'>'; 
        echo "opener.location.reload();"; 
        echo "window.close();"; 
    echo '\x3C/script>'; 
}
```

Its output needs to be surrounded by single quote.

```
echo 'document.write(\'', addCommentPHP() ,'\');';
```

Comment: This does not seem to work? The code is still generated the same as in Attempt 1

Comment: looks like too late, but I fixed it by using single quote.